# wpf Datagrid scroll gives error

Tags: wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

when I scroll in datagrid, I get an object reference error with below stack trace:

```
System.Windows.Controls.DataGridRow.RestoreAttachedItemValue(DependencyObject objectWithProperty, DependencyProperty property)
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataGridRow.SyncProperties(Boolean forcePrepareCells)
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataGridRow.PrepareRow(Object item, DataGrid owningDataGrid)
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.PrepareContainerForItemOverride(DependencyObject element, Object item)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl.MS.Internal.Controls.IGeneratorHost.PrepareItemContainer(DependencyObject container, Object item)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ItemContainerGenerator.System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.IItemContainerGenerator.PrepareItemContainer(DependencyObject container)
   at System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.InsertContainer(Int32 childIndex, UIElement container, Boolean isRecycled)
   at System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.AddContainerFromGenerator(Int32 childIndex, UIElement child, Boolean newlyRealized, Boolean isBeforeViewport)
   at System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureChild(IItemContainerGenerator& generator, IContainItemStorage& itemStorageProvider, IContainItemStorage& parentItemStorageProvider, Object& parentItem, Boolean& hasUniformOrAverageContainerSizeBeenSet, Double& computedUniformOrAverageContainerSize, Double& computedUniformOrAverageContainerPixelSize, Boolean& computedAreContainersUniformlySized, IList& items, Object& item, IList& children, Int32& childIndex, Boolean& visualOrderChanged, Boolean& isHorizontal, Size& childConstraint, Rect& viewport, VirtualizationCacheLength& cacheSize, VirtualizationCacheLengthUnit& cacheUnit, Boolean& foundFirstItemInViewport, Double& firstItemInViewportOffset, Size& stackPixelSize, Size& stackPixelSizeInViewport, Size& stackPixelSizeInCacheBeforeViewport, Size& stackPixelSizeInCacheAfterViewport, Size& stackLogicalSize, Size& stackLogicalSizeInViewport, Size& stackLogicalSizeInCacheBeforeViewport, Size& stackLogicalSizeInCacheAfterViewport, Boolean& mustDisableVirtualization, Boolean isBeforeFirstItem, Boolean isAfterFirstItem, Boolean isAfterLastItem, Boolean skipActualMeasure, Boolean skipGeneration, Boolean& hasBringIntoViewContainerBeenMeasured, Boolean& hasVirtualizingChildren)
   at System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl(Size constraint, Nullable`1& lastPageSafeOffset, List`1& previouslyMeasuredOffsets, Nullable`1& lastPagePixelSize, Boolean remeasure)
   at System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DataGridRowsPresenter.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayout()
   at System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayoutCallback(Object arg)
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.InvokeOnRenderCallback.DoWork()
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.FireInvokeOnRenderCallbacks()
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandlerCore(Object resizedCompositionTarget)
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandler(Object resizedCompositionTarget)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
```

I have used a datagrid, where inline editing is possible for the 3 columns `Min Value`, `Max Value` and `Correction Value`. After editing, I press <kbd>tab</kbd> and scroll the grid. The scrolling leads to the error message as mentioned above.

Please find the XAML code snippet below:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgUnitParameter"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserAddRows="True"
          ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
          CanUserDeleteRows="True"
          IsReadOnly="False"
          Grid.Row="1"
          Background="Transparent"
          SizeChanged="dgUnitParameter_SizeChanged"
          RowEditEnding="dgUnitParameter_RowEditEnding">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button x:Name="btnDelete"
                            ToolTipService.ToolTip="Delete"
                            Click="btnDelete_Click"
                            Style="{StaticResource IconButtonStyle}">
                        <Button.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                            <Image Source="..\..\Images\DeleteRed.png"/>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Button.Template>
                    </Button>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Parameter">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox x:Name="cmbParamterList"
                              SelectionChanged="cmbParamterList_SelectionChanged"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Parameters}"
                              DisplayMemberPath ="ParameterName"
                              SelectedValue="{Binding ParameterId, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged }"
                              SelectedValuePath="ParameterId"
                              Width="250" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>                    
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Parameter Type"
                            Binding="{Binding Path=ParameterType, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                            Width="150" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Parameter Unit"
                            Binding="{Binding Path=ParameterUnit, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                            Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button x:Name="btnMapping"
                            Click="btnMapping_Click"
                            ToolTipService.ToolTip="Mapping"
                            Style="{StaticResource IconButtonStyle}" Width="20">
                        <Button.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <Image Source="..\..\Images\ParameterMapping.png"/>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Button.Template>
                    </Button>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Tag Name"
                            IsReadOnly="true"
                            Binding="{Binding Path=TagName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                            Width="250"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Min Value"
                            Binding="{Binding Path=ParameterMinValue, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                            Width="150">
            <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Max Value"
                            Binding="{Binding Path=ParameterMaxValue, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                            Width="150">
            <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Correction Value"
                            Binding="{Binding Path=ParameterCorrectedValue, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                            Width="150">
            <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>              
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Can anyone help me out with this?

Regards,
Ruchi Patel

Comment: can you be a little more specific than this?

Comment: please find updated quetion.

Comment: Try disabling virtualization to verify whether this problem is virtualization specific (it should be). If you have a low amount of items and you don't need virtualization, you can probably stop there. Otherwise please create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so others can test your problem and possible solutions without re-inventing all the bindings and methods that are part of your XAML but not provided as code.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. it works well now.